# Join multiple values from function paramter into an array

Tags: javascript

```
var items = function (selector) {
    var elements = [];
  var allDivs = elements.push(selector);
console.log(elements) // ["div"] script.js:13
                         ["img.some_class"] script.js:13
                         ["#some_id"] script.js:13
                         [".some_class"] script.js:13
                         ["input#some_id"] script.js:13
                         ["div#some_id.some_class"] script.js:13
                         ["div.some_class#some_id"] script.js:13
}
```

The console.log in chrome shows the values listed currently.

How would i group these returned values into a single array? I've tried using join but this either has no method with brackets, or just removes [""] and leaves just the value.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? An array containing all the selectors you've passed into this function?

Comment: yeah exactly that. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var selector = [
    ["div"],
    ["img.some_class"],
    ["#some_id"],
    [".some_class"],
    ["input#some_id"],
    ["div#some_id.some_class"],
    ["div.some_class#some_id"]
];

console.log(selector.reduce(function(result, current) {
    result.push(current[0]);
    return result;
}, []));
```

**Output**

```
[ 'div',
  'img.some_class',
  '#some_id',
  '.some_class',
  'input#some_id',
  'div#some_id.some_class',
  'div.some_class#some_id' ]
```